# editText only writes on one line, scrolls right?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an `editText` that fills half the screens width, and all of it's height. When I append text to it the text always starts halfway down the edit text height and when it gets to the edge to the `editText` it keeps writing, scrolling to the right. I want it to go to a new line, why isn't it? and why does it start half way down? At the moment the text on the left should be replicated on the right. AppendToEMulator writes to the terminal fine, but when i'm ssetting the text in the `editText` on the right there are no newlines from either the bytes received, probably as I convert it to a string and also none from when the end of the `editText` is reached, just keeps going right.

```
 <jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
        android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_above="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/outputBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emulatorView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#FF043241"
        android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine" />
```

In Java:

```
public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data) {

        dataReceived = new String(data);
        dataReceivedByte = dataReceived.getBytes();
        statusBool = true;
        ((MyBAIsWrapper) bis).renew(data);


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSession.appendToEmulator(dataReceivedByte, 0, dataReceivedByte.length);


        }});


    final String ReceivedText = mReceiveBox.getText().toString() + " "
            + new String(data);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mReceiveBox.setText(ReceivedText);
            mReceiveBox.setSelection(ReceivedText.length());

        }
    });

    viewHandler.post(updateView);





}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read about the properties of a TextView.  EditText inherits them. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that setting an inputType disables wordwrap via:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Even if I specify

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

it was still getting overridden.
As I do not need to type in the `editText` I simply removed the input type.